# How can I configure data source and jdbc driver using project-stages.yml?

Tags: wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to using wildfly-swarm with `project-stages.yml`

#### src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
  <persistence-unit name="somePU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>someDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="CALLBACK" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

#### src/main/resources/project-stages.yml

```
project:
  stage: default
---
project:
  stage: development
logger:
  level: DEBUG
swarm:
  jdbc:
    driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
  ds:
    name: someDS
    connection:
      url: jdbc:derby:memory:someDB;create=true
  port:
    offset: 200
---
project:
  stage: integration
---
project:
  stage: staging
---
project:
  stage: production
```

#### mvn -Dswarm.project.stage=development -jar target/some-server-swarm.jar

```
2017-01-07 18:09:48,782 ERROR [stderr] (main) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-01-07 18:09:48,782 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,782 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,783 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,783 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,783 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:37)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,783 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:44)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,783 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:35)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,784 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0007: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.someDS"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"some-server.war#somePU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.someDS]","jboss.persistenceunit.\"some-server.war#somePU\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.someDS]"]}
2017-01-07 18:09:48,784 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:280)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,784 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:95)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,784 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:475)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,784 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:612)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,784 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 7 more
2017-01-07 18:09:48,784 ERROR [stderr] (main) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-01-07 18:09:48,785 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,785 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,785 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,785 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,785 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:37)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,785 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:44)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,785 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:35)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,785 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0007: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.someDS"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"some-server.war#somePU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.someDS]","jboss.persistenceunit.\"some-server.war#somePU\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.someDS]"]}
2017-01-07 18:09:48,785 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:280)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,786 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:95)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,786 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:475)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,786 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:612)
2017-01-07 18:09:48,786 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 7 more
```

Comment: Have a look at the example: https://howto.wildfly-swarm.io/create-a-datasource/

Comment: @simas_ch Yes I found the link after I posted the question. And I'm still failing the value for `<jta-data-source/>`

Answer (score 3):

I'm sharing my solution for others.

#### src/main/resources/project-stages.yml

As, [simas_ch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045142/simas-ch) noted, [How to create a datasource](https://howto.wildfly-swarm.io/create-a-datasource/) is enough to fix this part.

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      someDS:
        driver-name: h2
        connection-url: jdbc:h2:mem:someDB
```

#### src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

This part is always the most painful one. I had to do like this.

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/someDS</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to post the JNDI name. I'm sorry and happy that you found the solution by yourself.Wildfly Swarm has still very limited documentation. Hope this will be better in the future.